# Installing newer version of Ubuntu on top of older one

Tags: 20.04, 12.10

I have an old ThinkPad X300 running Ubuntu 12.10 and got Ubuntu 20.04 on a USB drive, when I boot live and try to install one of the options says:
Erase Ubuntu 12.10 and reinstall, does this option mean it'll just replace all programs and keep /home/* user accounts intact? The scary thing here it has a warning below it they says it will delete your Ubuntu 12.10 programs, documents, photos, music, and any other files which seems its going to wipe /home folder (since it's not a separate partition now)

Because the other option is to erase disk and install Ubuntu, I know this deleted all on disk including windows partition

And of course the last option is 'Something else', shall I select it and manually I select the Ubuntu partition without selecting format and try to install 20.04 on top of what's there and it won't delete /home? But if that's the case what about other folders like /etc etc.. It might leave lots of conflicting files of 12.10?

Because I didn't want to copy /home to flash disk and start fresh and wish to keep them there and possible reinstall without touching /home folder

Thanks :)

Comment: If you make the correct selection, the Ubuntu installer will try very hard to preserve your data. But that's not a guarantee. This site is soaked with the tears of people who did not back up their data, and then lost everything because of a mistake, misunderstanding, or typo. Don't be one of them.

Comment: Can't use something else because it won't show the swap partition and it'll be shooting in the dark and risk. @user535733

Answer (score 0):

You weren't specific as to if you're talking about installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server.  I'll assume Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop.

Most default options use a *clean* install which includes format, meaning prior data is lost. Erase disk & install is a perfectly example of that, other options will try and keep your user directory (only erasing the system directories) which is the next safest installation after a clean install.

Your asked for option is using "Something else", selecting your used partitions and ensuring you don't format them.  It'll cause the installer `ubiquity` to

- note your installed packages
- erase system directories (which include /etc you specifically mention)
- install new system
- attempt to add back your additional packages (noted earlier IF available in the new release)
- no user file in $HOME is touched unless you selected format
- ask you to reboot.

As server programs often store config/.conf files in system directories, this is **not** as useful for Ubuntu Server *upgrade via reinstall* purposes, as recovery from backups will be required for those files, but all desktop apps store configs in $HOME (user directory) so those are not touched.

Of course backups should still be performed, and not a 2012-October (12.10) release was a long time before 2020-April (20.04) so I'd expect to see a message warning you some packages could not be restored at the conclusion of the install, as you've missed a lot of intended upgrades between which dealt with some of those issues (*recent change exampples are in 2019 Python2 reached EOL, Qt4 was dropped noticed in the 18.04->20.04 bump, but you've got other years of changes too in there that I can't recall any longer*)

Comment: A 12.10 release was not a LTS or *long-term-support* release so QA-testing was performed only to the next release (13.04) and not to other releases. Yes automated upgrade testing was performed further than that, but you're way outside of intended upgrade paths (one release to the next and/or LTS release to the next LTS release). Your risk in my experience will be user apps that may not cope with config files as you've missed so many intended upgrade steps, but this maybe *quirks* and hard to detect

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported upgrade path from 12.10 directly to 20.04.

The recommended method is to backup your data and clean-install 20.04.

You can certainly try other methods (it's your system), including "*Erase 12.10 and reinstall*" offered by the 20.04 installer. Maybe it will work properly. Maybe it won't. A LOT has changed in eight years.

We have not tested that option on 12.10-to-20.04, and we won't provide support if it fails at doing something untested...beyond advising a clean-install. If you want certainty, back up your data.

Comment: I would invest in a external usb hard drive & backup your data. It looks like too much could go wrong.